# JQuery Slider animation

Tags: jquery

I would like to animate that slider, 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-animate so basically when it moves to from one to the other position movement is smooth,
i implemented that code but it doesn't work for me:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", ui.index );
            }


        });
        $( "#slider" ).slider({


            min: 0,
            max: $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "length" ) - 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select", ui.value );


                },


            animate: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you setup a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle which should correspond to his problem : http://jsfiddle.net/9ycNg/  Indeed the slider doesn't animate, if does if you remove the "slider { ... }" part.

Comment: here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/meyson/DryTf/

Comment: Thanks Sylvain
It works when you click on tubs, however i would like it to work when i click on slider itself, 
Sorry guys i'm newbie if it comes to JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: It does not work with this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9ycNg/3/ ?     It animates both when I click on the slider and / or the tabs for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You broke the animation when you set the `slide: { ... }` options. Adding `$(this).slide();` fixes the animation

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#slider").slider("value", ui.index);
        }
    });
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: $("#tabs").tabs("length") - 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#tabs").tabs("select", ui.value);
            $(this).slide(); // fixes the animation
        },
        animate: true
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ycNg/3/)

Comment: @jmysona: If it helped, accept the answer by clicking on the right arrow besides the answer ;)